# ActionListener Button does nothing

Tags: java

this button does nothing what would be the mistake?

its a login, I dont know why it doesnt work seems pretty well, could somebody help me to indentify the issue?.....................................................................................................................

```
   package Operaciones_Logicas;

   import Mainargs.FirstClass;
   import java.awt.event.*;
   import javax.swing.*;


    public class Main1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

   private JLabel usuario;
   private JLabel contraseña;
   public JButton blogin;
   public JTextField jtusuario, jtcontra;
   public static String susuario = "", scontra = "";

    public Main1() {
    setLayout(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Cajero Automatico");
    JLabel usuario = new JLabel();
    usuario.setVisible(true);
    usuario.setBounds(20, 100, 100, 50);
    add(usuario);

    JLabel contraseña = new JLabel();
    contraseña.setBounds(20, 300, 100, 50);
    add(contraseña);

    JButton blogin = new JButton("Login");
    blogin.setBounds(50, 400, 100, 30);
    blogin.addActionListener(this);
    add(blogin);

    JTextField jtusuario = new JTextField();
    jtusuario.setBounds(20, 120, 150, 30);
    add(jtusuario);

    JTextField jtcontra = new JTextField();
    jtcontra.setBounds(20, 150, 150, 30);
    add(jtcontra);

}

     //control para el login
     @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

     if (e.getSource() == blogin) {

        susuario = jtusuario.getText();
        scontra = jtcontra.getText();

        if (susuario.equals("josmart96") && (scontra.equals("rojo2000"))) {
            FirstClass secondwindow = new FirstClass();
            secondwindow.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 360);
            secondwindow.setVisible(true);
            secondwindow.setResizable(false);
            secondwindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            this.setVisible(false);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuario y/o Contraseña 
          incorrectas");
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main1 firstwindow = new Main1();
    firstwindow.setBounds(0, 0, 360, 600);
    firstwindow.setVisible(true);
    firstwindow.setResizable(false);
    firstwindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}
```

}

no erros just doesnt work, when hit button does nothing I can compile it and everything is good I think it could be the IDE itself

Comment: You assign your button to a local variable `blogin`, but your instance variable `blogin` is never assigned to anything. So `if (e.getSource() == blogin)` is false.

Comment: You define a new local variable `blogin` in your constructor. So the button is attached to that, not to the `blogin` in your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using local variable `blogin` instead of using instance variable `blogin`

Inside the contructor, change

```
JButton blogin = new JButton("Login");
```

to

```
blogin = new JButton("Login");
```

you also need to use other declared instance variables rather than declaring local variables inside the constructor

Comment: seems to work (the action) althought I get many errors in the console and still doesnt work

Comment: errors like

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Operaciones_Logicas.Main1.actionPerformed(Main1.java:50)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)

Comment: @JoseOmarGomez That's because of all the other fields that left set to null.

Comment: @JoseOmarGomez you need to use instance variables instead of declaring new variables with same name inside the constructor.

Comment: Wow man I was thinking about it like 1 entire day and now I realized that I got so confused about a basic thing thanks